# Migration and importing data from JIRA to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: import, migration, jira, azure-devops

we are involved in a migration of tools from Atlassian JIRA to Visual Studio Team Services. I'm looking for a suitable and fine way to export contents from JIRA in order to import in a safe way in VSTS.

Any suggestion is appreciated in order to find a good way to accomplish that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple project (such as console project) in VS, and then connected VSTS and JIRA, and import data from JIRA to VSTS.

Steps as: Create a console project in VS -> add nuget packages (Atlassian.SDK and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Client) -> define connection to VSTS -> define connection to JIRA -> get date from JIRA -> create work items and upload to VSTS.

Detail steps, you can refer [import from JIRA to VSTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2017/01/16/importing-from-jira-to-vsts/).